# Advanced Custom Field Front End Form not producing the right Slug/Permalink

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I've grabbed this code from the Advanced Custom Fields website to make an employee directory with a front-end ACF form. But I can't get it to produce a permalink that is the title employee name, which is the title of the post. It just produces a random number. Permalinks are set to Post Name Here is the code in my template file:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php

acf_form(array(
    'post_id'       => 'new_post',
    'post_title'    =>  wp_strip_all_tags($_POST['acf']['field_624c65c9cc5da']), // Post Title ACF field key
    'return' => '%post_url%',
    'new_post'      => array(
        'post_type'     => 'staff',
        'post_status'   => 'publish'
    )
));

?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

And this is the code in my functions PHP file:

```
add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_save_post', 20);
function my_save_post($post_id){
  
  // Get the data from a field
  $new_title = get_field('staff_name', $post_id);
  
  // Set the post data
  $new_post = array(
      'ID'           => $post_id,
      'post_title'   => $new_title,
  );
  
  // Remove the hook to avoid infinite loop. Please make sure that it has
  // the same priority (20)
  remove_action('acf/save_post', 'my_save_post', 20);
  
  // Update the post
  wp_update_post( $new_post );
  
  // Add the hook back
  add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_save_post', 20);
  
}
```

Comment: This is now also causing the Title of another CPT (Projects) to be empty when I update the post. Turning off the functions fixes that issue.

Comment: just to understand, if you disable your hook `acf/save_post`, does the ACF form still correctly create a new custom post of type "staff"? (i.e. are you using the `acf_form_head()` function too?)

Comment: also, documentation says `acf/save_post` hook can be used either BEFORE  or AFTER the post is saved, depending on the priority of the action. You set it to 20, the site says: `This example demonstrates how to perform additional functionality before ACF has saved the $_POST data by using a priority less than 10.` As far as I understand this, since the priority you set (20) is more than 10, your hook will be executed AFTER the post has been saved. Please try using a priority of 5, just like in the example provided here: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-save_post/

Comment: @GrafiCode I set the priority to 5. Then this is what happened: I submitted the form and the title didn't show. but when I hit save draft/publish it showed.